# Unhandled exception thrown: write access violation. tmp was 0x1110112. При сортировке слиянием

Tags: c, массивы, сортировка, сортировка-слиянием

Задание - создать сортировку слиянием (код представлен ниже). При 10000 елементов все норм (N1), но уже при 100 тыс выдает ошибку.

*Unhandled exception thrown: write access violation. tmp was 0x1110112.*

И выделяет строку

```
        else{
        >tmp[step] = a[j];<
        j++;
        }
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#define N1 100000


void mergeSort(int *a, int l, int r)
{
    if (l == r) return;
    int mid = (l + r) / 2; 
    
    mergeSort(a, l, mid);
    mergeSort(a, mid + 1, r);
    int i = l; 
    int j = mid + 1; 
    int *tmp = (int*)malloc(r * sizeof(int)); 
    for (int step = 0; step < r - l + 1; step++) 
    {
        
        if ((j > r) || ((i <= mid) && (a[i] < a[j])))
        {
            tmp[step] = a[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp[step] = a[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    
    for (int step = 0; step < r - l + 1; step++)
        a[l + step] = tmp[step];
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int A[N1];
    
    printf("Starter mas:\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < N1; i++)
    {
        A[i] = rand() % 101;
        printf("%2d ", A[i]);
    }


    mergeSort(A, 0, N1 - 1); 
    
    printf("\nSort mas:\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < N1; i++)
    {
        printf("%2d ", A[i]);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Си изучаю от силы месяц.

Comment: во первых переполнение памяти может быть. сначала удалите массив `free ( tmp ) ; `.  В конце `mergeSort`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно одной-двух строк отладочного вывода, чтоб увидеть, что тут

```
        tmp[step] = a[j];
```

вы выходите за рамки выделенной в количестве `r` памяти при

```
step == 1, r == 1, l == 0
```

Причина слета выяснена. Как убрать - догадайтесь сами :)

P.S. Не понимаю - сейчас в принципе программистов не учат использовать, например, `assert` или простейший отладочный вывод, если уж проблемы работой с отладчиком имеются?